# Passing a Python list of coordinates to add as markers to web map (Flask)

Tags: python, javascript, coordinates, web-mapping, flask

In my flask GIS app, I am passing my web map a list of coordinates from a route in my Python backend, which works as I expect it to. When I print the list it looks like this.

```
[['53.792614', '-1.789202'], ['53.792561', '-1.789223'], ['53.770554', '-1.751224'], ['53.712614', '-1.746287']] ...
```

I am then trying to add this list of coordinates to the map as markers, in my JavaScript. I am following HERE maps documentation - https://developer.here.com/documentation/examples/maps-js/markers/markers-on-the-map - and trying to loop through each coordinate in my list, creating a new marker for each.

```
// These variables are dependant on the flask route that is completed
    var lat = {{latitude}}     // 53.483837
    var long = {{longitude}}     // -2.225899
    var chargepoints = {{chargepoints}}
    var coords = {{radius_coordinates}}

// REST OF MAP FUNCTION OMITTED DUE TO LENGTH

    // chargepoints = 2 if the chargepoints route is completed
        if (chargepoints = 2) {
    
          // ADD THE CHARGEPOINTS TO THE MAP
          for (var i=0; i<coords.length; i++) {
    
            var chargemarker = new H.map.Marker({lat:coords[i][1], lng: coords[i][0]}); Cmap.addObject(chargemarker);
    
            Cmap.addObject(chargemarker);
        }
        }
```

However when I do this, the map does not load, and I get the error - Uncaught SyntaxError: expected expression, got '&' - in my console, and I don't know where the problem is. When I look in the Web Inspector, the coords variable looks like this.

```
var coords = [&#39;53.712614&#39;, &#39;-1.746287&#39;]
```

Comment: I think this is going to be incredibly difficult for someone to offer help. Are you getting a line number from the error that could help you narrow down the problem? It could be happening all sorts of places, but a guess is the response you're parsing has something your code doesn't expect.

Comment: You could start adding a bunch of `print( ... )` in your Python code, especially in the loops. It might show the last line and what the values were. Its been awhile since I worked with Flask, I'm not sure if you can inject a `console.log(...)` and have it actually output.

Comment: I've edited down my question, the Python route works as expected the problem is in passing the coordinates to my javascript and adding them to my map.

Comment: The console usually should show the location in code where the error ocurred. Can you track it down this way?

Comment: Yeah, what line is blowing up? The `addObject`? Best guess is something was parsed incorrectly and its sending junk to addObject and trying to draw that on the map. But it's so hard to guess without debugging. And try passing in only a single coordinate. Make sure that basic functionality works. Can you draw 1?

Comment: I tried passing one coordinate, same result. When I try to view the source of the error in the debugger it says "line not found". I looked at the inspector and coords is being named like this - var coords = [&#39;53.712614&#39;, &#39;-1.746287&#39;] - all other variables are as expected.

Comment: There ya go. `&#39` sounds like its the string conversion issue (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29314231/what-is-39-and-why-does-google-search-replace-it-with-apostrophe/29314258) - those used to be quotes, but your app is translating them to the escaped values. Your "fix" might be as sample as building up your list with `floats`. IE. `float(device['ChargeDeviceLocation']['Latitude'])` when making  `radius_coordinates` in the Python side of things.

Comment: Thanks! If you want to write this as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the error and debug message, your Python code is passing a string into the JavaScript / web side of things. This literal string is being escaped, and the escaped characters are being passed into the JavaScript code to put items on the map.

So, in your Python code you have:
`['53.792614', '-1.789202']`

What JavaScript is passing to the mapping function:
`[&#39;53.712614&#39;, &#39;-1.746287&#39;]`

There are probably a few different places to fix this, but I'd suggest fixing it within Python by converting the strings to doubles. From your Python code, you could do that when you build up list to plot:
`float(device['ChargeDeviceLocation']['Latitude'])`